# Angular custom module cannot be found in a different machine

Tags: angular

I have created an Angular app that includes different classes and modules, I have built it successfully in my machine and I have pushed it to a git repository.

Now, I have pulled it in a different machine and it cannot be build since it cannot find some of my classes.

The error messages says `error TS2307: Cannot find module '../entities/events/Event'`

The class that cannot be found looks like this:

```
export class Event {
  "priority": number;
  "time": string;
  "event": string;
  "uid_inst": number;
  "name": string;
}
```

- I made sure these modules are included in my version control.
- I am using the same Angular version in both machines (8.2.14)
- I have defined similar classes that are found without problem
- I have deleted node_modules and run npm install, although the modules that cannot be found are part of the repository.

Comment: Post some of the code of the module that can't be found.

Comment: `Cannot find module` sounds like a TypeScript error to me, and not related to Angular `NgModule`. So please update with the exact error message.

Comment: Just done!  @Mickers

Comment: I don't think this is your problem but you don't need quotes around your property names. You also are missing your constructor. constructor(data?: Event) { this.priority = data.priority ? data.priority : null ...}. I also would not name your class 'Event'. That is a pretty commonly used name in Js which could cause typescript issues.

Comment: @Mickers Do I need a constructor if  I am using this as a model class?

Comment: @fa__ if you don't want to take advantage of using a class than change this to an interface. There's no point in using a class if you don't add a constructor so you can create instances of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care of the folder and file name cases. I had a similar problem with windows and Linux.

Try with:

```
../entities/events/event
```

Instead of:

```
../entities/events/Event
```

Comment: That was the problem! My first machine was Windows and allowed the upper cases.

Answer (score 0):

Consider deleting `node_modules` folder and `run npm install`.

Comment: I have already tried this without success. I will edit my question to clarify this.